# getting wrong/invalid navigation in spring-mvc web application

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying a simple web application to implement CRUD operations. When I run my application on tomcat-7 then i get my home page. When I click on 'add Spcr' link then it shows addSpcr.jsp form page. After filling form when I click on save then its giving me following error:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /insert
description:requested resource is not available
```

addSpcr.jsp page:

```
 <form method="POST" action="/insert" >
 //form body
 </form>
```

When I hit on save button then ideally it should navigate to

```
https://localhost:8080/SampleLeaderTool/insert
```

but its navigating to url

```
https://localhost:8080/insert
```

Method from controller is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/insert",method = RequestMethod.POST) 
public ModelAndView insertData(@ModelAttribute Spcr spcr){
    if (spcr != null)  
           a.insertData(spcr); 

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("success");
    return model;
}
```

view resolver from spring-servlet.xml:

```
<bean id="viewResolver"  
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">  
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />  
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />  
</bean>
```

I am not able to figure out what I did wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are missing a context path in your form action.

To avoid this kind of issues include: `${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}` before `/insert`.

For e.g.:

```
 <form method="POST" action="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/insert" >
 //form body
 </form>
```

Comment: error message: http status 404     The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect

Comment: It means that you are submitting something wrong to the server. Adding context path worked, so you have to check what is wrong in your form body.

Answer (score 0):

you can write this code.hope this is work.

```
<form method="POST" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/insert" >
 //form body
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to include `${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}` before doing an insertion, becaus it's missing the path for the context of the action